# When does `n` match last digits of `n^2`?

Tags: python, algorithm, numeric

I'm solving one programming problem.

> Find all numbers `x` from `1` to `n` that have a property that digits
>   of `x` match digits at the end of `x^2`.

For example:

```
5 matches last digit of 5^2 (25)
6 matches last digit of 6^2 (36)
25 matches last digits of 25^2 (625)
76 matches last digits of 76^2 (5776)
376 matches last digits of 376^2 (141376)
625 matches last digits of 625^2 (390625)
etc.
```

Does anyone know what the numerical criteria is for a number to match itself in last digits of it squared?

I'm programming this in Python and I can only use numeric operations such as `/`, `%`, `//`, `*`, `+`, etc.

I can't use `str` or `len` or string functions to slice numbers.

Comment: Could you add the exact phrasing of the problem in question? Also, this question may be more on topic on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, one moment please

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A003226

Comment: Why don't you find more values that match and look for a pattern?  It's hard to go by just 3 examples.

Comment: I will add more examples.

Comment: so then just check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_number for a formula.

Comment: Programming problem is O(n). This is more of math problem then a programming.

Comment: Please see my own answer and please comment. I figured out. I check last digits always, then drop last digit, then check again. Until all digit check!!!!!!!

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I think it's log(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I wrote this answer:

```
n=int(input('n='))

for m in range(1, n+1):
    d=m**2
    x = m

    all = 0
    all2 = 0

    while x != 0:
        if x%10 == d%10:
            all += 1
        x = x//10
        d = d//10
        all2 += 1

    if all == all2:
        print m
```

Please let me know what you think -- it works!

Answer (score 4):

Say x has k digits. Then x^2 ends with the digits of x if and only if x^2 - x ends with k zeroes, i.e., if x(x-1) ends with k zeroes.

Count the number of times 2 goes into x and into x-1 (the sum), then do the same for 5. If the min of those is at least as big as the number of digits, you have a winner. If not, you don't.

E.g, Consider 5. 5 goes into 5 once and into 4 zero times, 2 goes into 5 zero times and into 4 twice. The min of 1 and 2 is one. 5 has one digit, so you have a winner.

---

The easy way to find all such numbers between 1 and n is to just check multiples of powers of 5. Since for each k digit number, you need 5^k to be a factor, check 5^k and all multiples that don't exceed k digits. This could be x or x-1, so you'll also need to check the number above.

So the numbers to check are:

```
k=1: 5, 6
k=2: 25, 26, 50, 51, 75, 76
k=3: 125, 126, 250, 251, 375, 376, 500, 501, 625, 626, 750, 751, ...
k=4: 625, 626, 1250, 1251, ...
```

etc...

And all you need to check for any of these is if the min set bit gets you at least k 2s.

Note that 625 shows up for both k=3 and k=4, but that's fine since 0625 is valid. In practice you only need to check once, so you can limit yourself to the multiples which are themselves at least k digits.

Comment: Or for 376: we have 2 going into 376 3 times and 375 zero times. We have 5 going into 376 zero times and into 375 3 times. Min(3,3)=3, and 376 is 3 digits, so you have another winner. Obviously you only need to check the even number for 2s, and can quickly find the first set bit. Checking for 5s is log time.

Comment: This just checks one number. To find all the good numbers between 1 and n, this would be nlog(n), so maybe too slow. Note that if x is divisible by both 2 and 5 then x-1 isn't divisible by either. But then if the min is k, x >= 10^k, and has at least k+1 digits, so won't be a winner. Thus you only need to look a numbers x where x is divisible by either 2 or 5, and x-1 is divisible by the other. Thus for any number of digits k, you need to look at 5^k and (5^k)+1. For each of these, check the number of 2s. If it is good, take that number and any multiple that doesn't increase the digits.

Comment: Simple algorithm is o(n). Just iterate and check that `(x^2 - x)%(10*(floor(log10(x)) + 1)) == 0`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri as opposed to log(n).

Comment: You say that your algorithm is nlog(n). I have shown you n algorithm. Or I have just misunderstood something. Can you explain in more details why your algorithm for findind all such numbers between 1 and n is log(n)?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri No, you're right. Mine is also O(n). Credit a sleepy brain. But it's a much faster O(n) in practice since you're checking far fewer numbers. I.e., identical to yours but only checking 2^(log base 10 of n) numbers instead of n.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete criteria, but it can be used as a start point:

First: recall that the last digit in a multiplication is the last digit of the multiplication of the last digit of the first operand times the last digit of the second operand.

As the multiplication is of one number by itsef, the possible combinations are: 0x0, 1x1, 2x2, 3x3, 4x4, 5x5, 6x6, 7x7, 8x8, and 9x9.

The multiplications which have the same last digit as its operands are 0x0, 1x1, 5x5 and 6x6.

So you can start by testing only numbers that end in 0, 1, 5 or 6.

For each of these digits, you can build a two digit number, by prepending a digit 1, 2, 3, ..., 9 to them. So, for digit 0, you have 10,20,30,...,90 . You have to find now which of these numbers, multiplied by itsef, produces a result whose next to last digit is the same as it. Let this two digit number be `10a+b` where `a` is the tens and `b` is the ones. The value of `b` is already fixed and is one of 0, 1, 5 or 6. Set a value for `b` and let (10a+b)(10a+b) which is `100a^2 + 20ab + b^2` be the result of multiplying 10a+b by itsef.

We are interested in the tens of this number, so we divide it into `10`, resulting `10a^2 + 2ab + b^2/10` and do a 10 modulus to isolate the tens digit. Substitute the value of `b` in the expression, performing an integer division for the last term. For example, for `b=5`, the expression would be `(10a^2 + 20*5*a + 2) mod 10`. Make this expression to be equal to `a` and you've got an equation that gives you what values of `a` match the equality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm trying to understand it and to implement it. :) Can you also please check my solution that I posted as answer to my own question?

Comment: I don't know anything about Python but it seems a straightforward solution. If you have tested it and it works, then it works :) I have made a quick test running it using Coding Ground, and testing with n=1000000 and works.

Comment: For k digits you only need to check multiples of 5^k and such multiples plus 1. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay This is the edited version:

```
LastNum=int(input("Enter end limit: "))
def y(num):
    count=0
    while num!=0:
        num=num//10
        count=count+1
    return count
def LastDigitMatch(x):
    if x%(10**y(x))==(x**2)%(10**y(x)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
print('The required list of numbers: ')
for num in range(1,LastNum+1):
    if LastDigitMatch(num):
        print(num,end=', ')
```

I found [Giorgi Nakeuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651298/giorgi-nakeuri/)'s version (see comment on Dave Galvin's post) the fastest and the simplest among all. I edited the code:

```
import math
LastNum=int(input("Enter the end limit: "))
print('The required list of numbers:')    
for x in range(1,LastNum+1):
    if x%(10**math.floor(math.log10(x)+1))==(x**2)%(10**math.floor(math.log10(x)+1)):
        print(x,end=', ')
```

Comment: Not work for numbers >= 10... Only work for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Problem: You have to check ALL last digits. For example: your program matches "16" but 16^2 is  256 and 16 is not at end of 256. Need check ALL digits end.!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh right! I misunderstood your question. I though last didt of x matches last digit of x^2. my bad. Editting it.

Comment: Thank you! I want to see your answer thanks please very much!

Comment: Added!! Again for python 2.x please change the last line to:
print num,

Comment: This works great, but it's slow for large values of n.

Comment: Yes, I should have used a log function instead of the y(x) function. I editted the code and implemented Giorgi Nakeuri's algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

A function which returns a **list** of these numbers.

```
def mathcing_squared(n):
    return [x for x in range(1, n + 1) if str(x ** 2).endswith(str(x))]
```

So if **n** is **650**, it will return

```
[1, 5, 6, 25, 76, 376, 625]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.